# Can I select and concat all parent id of the tree in mysql?

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

I have table like this:

```
+--------+---------+
| Id     | Pid     |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |       0 |
|      2 |       1 |
|      3 |       2 |
|      4 |       3 |
|      5 |       3 |
|      6 |       2 |
+--------+---------+
```

I want to select all parents id of a record and concat them like this:

```
+--------+---------+
| ID     | pidList |
+--------+---------+
|        |         |
|      1 |0        |
|      2 |1,0      |
|      3 |2,1,0    |
|      4 |3,2,1,0  |
|      5 |3,2,1,0  |
|      6 |2,1,0    |
+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Maybe you should check this. http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza: thanks! you're right